# OECD package in R and problem with downloading data

Tags: r

I am trying to download data directly from the OECD website using the OECD package in R. I'm specifically trying to download data from Database on Immigrants in OECD countries (DIOC)
or more precisly data DIOC_CITIZEN_AGE Immigrants by citizenship and age. In order to do that I wrote this lines of codes:

```
library(OECD)
library(dplyr)

data_bases<-search_dataset("immigrants", data = get_datasets(), ignore.case= TRUE)
dataset <-"DIOC_CITIZEN_AGE"
get_dataset(dataset = dataset,filter = list(c("AUS", "EST")), start_time = 2010,
              end_time = 2020)
```

After execution code above I get the following error

```
Bad Request (HTTP 400).Error in rsdmx::readSDMX(url) : HTTP request failed with status: 400
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: http error 400 points to a bad request, i.e. the server will or cannot execute the request. I do not know the OECD or rsdmx package, but the error points to rsdmx::readSDMX(url). Is your url correctly formatted and comprises the https request in the right format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have a look at the description of variables in this dataset:

```
dataset <- "DIOC_CITIZEN_AGE"
dstruc <- get_data_structure(dataset)
dstruc$VAR_DESC
```

You'll see that the first variable is `COUB` (Country of birth)

Looking at the possible values for this variable:

```
dstruc$COUB
```

You'll find out that EST is not listed as a possible country (did you mean USSR-EST?), so the following works:

```
df <- get_dataset(dataset = dataset, filter = list(c("AUS")))
```

Apparently, there is no `TIME` variable in this dataset, so the `start_time` and `end_time` arguments are not working either.